# Tomcat http error status label is different

Tags: http, tomcat, servlet-filters

We recently did the migration from JBoss EAP 5.2 to Tomcat 8 and we're having an issue with http error handling.

Our front-end client uses the error message of the http error to handle the error.

When looking at the http response headers of the request on both servers we see the following:

> JBOSS : **Status code:** (o)401 OUR_CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE
>
> Tomcat 8 : **Status code:** (o)401 Unauthorized

The error is thrown by the following code in our filter:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
```

Any idea how to make Tomcat 8 take the error message in the status code header instead of the generic "Unauthorized"?

Thanks.

Comment: Curious - what's the reason to choose Tomcat 8 over WildFly 10?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using the Tomcat configuration parameter `org.apache.coyote. USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` and setting it to `true`